# What is happening with this border?

Tags: css

I was playing around with CSS borders and did this:

```
border-style: double dashed dashed solid;
```

Can someone explain why it does this? Changing the `border-width` also does strange things.

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/nenibeyujo/1/edit)

[image: screenshot of odd border]

Comment: The CSS is self explanatory. You are setting different border styles for the top right bottom left edges of the shape

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn It did not explain itself to me. Thank you for the insight in any case.

Comment: You should include sufficient code that illustrates the issue *in the question itself* and also specify exactly what is the *problem*.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Exactly how much more code is required to constitute a sufficiency beyond the line of CSS that produces the effect I describe?

Comment: CSS as such does nothing. It needs to be applied to some HTML or XML element. Besides, you are clearly having some `border-radius`. And you did not specify the browser(s) used. What is required is a completele (though preferably minimal) HTML document with CSS that actually produces the result, the identification of the browser(s), and a description of how the actual rendering differs from the expected rendering.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Nah, the CSS, a screenshot, and a JSBin are definitely sufficient sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you write `border-style: double dashed dashed solid;` you set the border style for all four sides of the border at once. You can read it as `border-style: <top> <right> <bottom> <left>;` so it's shorthand for:

```css
border-top-style: double;
border-right-style: dashed;
border-bottom-style: dashed;
border-left-style: solid;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, whatever the question is.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela This fully answers the question.

Comment: No, the jsbin in the question renders differently in different browsers, and this does not address that. And there *is* no well-defined question.

Answer (score 2):

You can have it with this css too, using solid borders in `bottom` `right` `left` and double in `top` cause this. borders on top that has `double` style and border on other sides like first image and if you round the solid or dashed border like second image produce your shape. it if like when you have a metal frame of an image and round it. See there examples too:

1. See this:

[image: One]

```
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 gray;
border-color: red;
border-radius: 0;
border-style: double solid solid solid; // top, right, bottom, left
border-width: 15px;
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
```

if you round borders using `border-radius` to `50%` then it becomes:

2. The Round:

   border-radius: 50%;

[image: Two]

and if you have `inset` in the top cause this:

```
border-style: inset solid solid solid; // top, right, bottom, left
```

[image: Three]

Comment: This does not answer the question. None of the images matches the one in the question, still less answers the “why” question.